# Understand this avionics indicator

Tags: indicator

I have a number of avionics instruments that I try to get to work, as a hobby. I bought a particular instrument off of eBay which I cant seem to figure out.

[image: Instrument]
[image]

The instrument is supposedly powered by 28V, not further specified. I opened the instrument and found a bunch of resistors and three identical type of indicators. One of these indicators I pulled further out to study and to make it "move".

The indicator consists of:

- a permanent magnet at the core
- a spool around that core with a limited number of windings. This spool is the moving part and
  connects to the needle of the indicator.
- Around the spool and connected to the inner magnet is a iron/steel "stator" with a *variable* thickness (I think that is a significant detail).

The spool is connected to two wires, both of these connect to different resistor pairs in the back of the instrument and then connect to a pin. Then there is a single wire connected on top of the indicator which is not connected to anything.

[image: Rear view, spool and two wires]
[image: Top view]
[image: Rear view, spool and two wires]
[image: Front view]

My question then. Is anyone familiar with this type of movement / indication mechanism. And what would be a logical pin out. I was thinking 1 phase 28VAC 400Hz (common aircraft power source) but I wouldn't know how this would allow the needle to point to a specific point on the dial. Unfortunately I don't have such power source.

[image: Simplified schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faqWnc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I tried DC over the two wires (green+gray) connected to the spool and this moves the needle a little, to its centering position. Not sure what to think of the 3rd wire.

Extensive internet searches for patents etc didn't yield any result as how this may work. But maybe I miss the correct keywords.

Appreciate any input!

Disclaimer: I have limited knowledge of electrical engineering, currently following the MIT 6.002. Please let me know if there is anything I can do to improve this question.

Comment: S122 3000 PSI refers to a pressure transducer. The one you pulled apart in the pictures doesn't look like the 3-needle one at the top, is it different?

Comment: It is the same one (I bought two). The needle assembly I pulled out is one of the symmetric main pressure indicators.

Comment: Intuitively, I'd assume it has two inputs for the pressure sensors of left and right brakes (green and grey) and a common terminal (purple). The fact that there are 3 indicators makes it likely that there must be more than one input signal...

Comment: If it indeed is meant for 28V *AC*, you better don't supply it with 28V DC. Inductors have a very low resistance for direct current..

Comment: thanks, sorry if I didn't make this clear. The 3 wires are for one indicator. The instrument has 9 pins total, each indicator (needle) has 3 separate wires with 2 going through the resistors to the spool and 1 to the "top".

Comment: What happens if you put a small DC current (say ~100uA) through a given pair of wires?  Something like a 9V battery with 100K in series.

Comment: The needle / indicator will move to the position where the "stator" (steel outer ring) has its thinnest point (it has a variable thickness, see picture). This is more or less the midpoint position.

Comment: It turns out this is a moving coil galvanometer. The zeroing spring is not clearly visible but it is there in the form of a very thin wire. 

Still need to figure out the wiring exactly. Will update the question with an answer once I have all the details.